# Using Netflix Conductor with a different backend

Tags: orchestration, netflix-conductor

Has anyone used Netflix Conductor with a completely different backend . We are thinking to plug in the Conductor with Azure Cosmos DB as backend .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Conductor by design has a pluggable architecture which means as long as you implement the storage interfaces you can use any data store. In the OSS there is community contributions for MySQL and other stores.